# Android Camera Callback Buffer Empty

Tags: c#, android, camera, xamarin.android

I am having a problem with the camera CallBack Buffer. The camera adds 4 new callbackbuffers, and also associates the byte Array to a dictionary mBytesToByteBuffer with the form (Byte[], ByteBuffer). I believe the problem lies with the fact the dictionary never updates its keys to the most recent frame. Leading to comparisons with current frame data failing. And the code not progressing past that point.

I have looked through the google example I have been working through, and it seems that they do not update their mBytesToByteBuffer at all, but that it seems to work.

From having looked at the source code for both AddCallbackBuffer and SetPreviewCallbackWithBuffer, it seems that they do not do anything with the byte arrays passed to them.

Declaration of mBytesToByteBuffer

```
public ConcurrentDictionary<byte[], ByteBuffer> mBytesToByteBuffer = new ConcurrentDictionary<byte[], ByteBuffer>();
```

Adding the CallbackBuffers:

```
camera.AddCallbackBuffer(createPreviewBuffer(mPreviewSize));
camera.AddCallbackBuffer(createPreviewBuffer(mPreviewSize));
camera.AddCallbackBuffer(createPreviewBuffer(mPreviewSize));
camera.AddCallbackBuffer(createPreviewBuffer(mPreviewSize));
camera.SetPreviewCallbackWithBuffer(new CameraPreviewCallback(this));
```

The dictionary mBytesToByteBuffer contains the correct size of byteArray, however this is never populated.

The Byte Buffer Dictionary is created here.

```
       private byte[] createPreviewBuffer(Size previewSize)
    {
        int bitsPerPixel = ImageFormat.GetBitsPerPixel(ImageFormatType.Nv21);
        long sizeInBits = previewSize.Height * previewSize.Width * bitsPerPixel;
        int bufferSize = (int)System.Math.Ceiling(sizeInBits / 8.0d) + 1;

        byte[] byteArray = new byte[bufferSize];
        ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.Wrap(byteArray);
        if (!buffer.HasArray)
        {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Failed to create valid buffer for camera source.");
        }
        mBytesToByteBuffer[byteArray] = buffer; //(byteArray, buffer);

        return byteArray;
    }
```

The callBackBuffer is called here through mBytesToByteBuffer

```
public void setNextFrame(byte[] data, Android.Hardware.Camera camera)
        {
            lock (mLock)
            {
                if (mPendingFrameData != null)
                {
                    camera.AddCallbackBuffer(mPendingFrameData.ToArray<System.Byte>());
                    mPendingFrameData = null;
                }
                if (!cameraSource.mBytesToByteBuffer.ContainsKey(data))
                {
                    Log.Debug(TAG, "Skipping Frame, Could not Find ByteBuffer Associated with image");
                    return;

                }
                mPendingTimeMillis = SystemClock.ElapsedRealtime() - mStartTimeMillis;
                mPendingFrameId++;
                mPendingFrameData = cameraSource.mBytesToByteBuffer[data];
                Monitor.PulseAll(mLock);
            }
        }
```

But the code never gets past

```
if(!cameraSource.mBytesToByteBuffer.containsKey(data)
```

Data is fully populated.

CameraPreviewCallback:

```
    private class CameraPreviewCallback : Java.Lang.Object, Android.Hardware.Camera.IPreviewCallback
    {
        CameraSource cameraSource;

        public CameraPreviewCallback(CameraSource cs)
        {
            cameraSource = cs;
        }

        public void OnPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Android.Hardware.Camera camera)
        {
            cameraSource.mFrameProcessor.setNextFrame(data, camera);
        }
    }
```

I have been working through the [Google Vison Example Camera Source](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-vision/blob/master/visionSamples/barcode-reader/app/src/main/java/com/google/android/gms/samples/vision/barcodereader/ui/camera/CameraSource.java)

[My Full Camera Source](https://github.com/StormMaster12/StockApp/blob/master/StockApp/UI/CameraSource.cs)

Comment: data byte array that comes to you in onPreviewFrame callback is always one if the buffers that you used for AddCallbackBuffer(). As soon as you are done with these pixels, you should call AddCallbackBuffer() again to let the Camera put use it to put new pixels.

Comment: @AlexCohn Ok, I think I get that, but how do I get mBytesToByteBuffer to populate?

Comment: The truth is, I don't understand the motivation behind the mBytesToByteBuffer. Why not use the byte array that comes from camera directly?

Comment: For the buffer empty issue, it is possible a [bug](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36924734).

Comment: Ok @GraceFeng-MSFT, i will give what is suggested there a go.

Comment: @AlexCohn I got stuck on this today and found out that google vision CameraSource filters out any frameData that is received on separate buffers. It forces the same buffer objects to be used as was supplied originally during the camera.addCallbackBuffer() method.